# problems to solve function for more then 2 buttons

Tags: javascript

I have the problem to set the right form for the js to let each button show more or less for each div (echo '';) part. It's just an logic part which I can't figure out how to set it in my code to get an normal running function. What I tried is commented out in the script part.

**what i tried:**
If I let the code as it is the buttons innerHTML text change but nothing else.

If I change the

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content")[0];
```

I get the problem that the button innerHTML change and also the first button opens, but the class .show-less-content would be removed overwirtten or what ever and thats it.

If I set the code

```
var content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content")[0];
```

In the for loop I get could open the divs just numerical once. Each button I click first I open the first div. each button I click at 2nd I get the 2nd div opend within loosing the class formating
and so on...
how can i set the javascript part right to let each button show more or less on each click? thx, br

```
<style>
  .show-less-content { 
    min-width:          100%;
    width:              100%;
    background:         #fff;
    padding:            0px;
    padding-top:        0;
    font-family:        calibri;
    font-size:          18px;
    color:              #444;
    margin:             0;
    max-height:         105px;
    overflow:           hidden;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition:    max-height 0.7s;
    transition:         max-height 0.7s;
  }
  .open{
    max-height:         100%;
    -webkit-transition: max-height 0.7s;
    -moz-transition:    max-height 0.7s;
    transition:         max-height 0.7s;
  }
```

```
<script>
  if (document.readyState == 'loading') {
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', ready)
  } else {
    ready()
  }
  function ready() {
    //var content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content")[0];
    var content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content");
    var showButton = document.getElementsByClassName("show-more");
    for (var i = 0; i < showButton.length; i++) {
      showButton[i].addEventListener('click', function(event){
        var buttonLessMore = event.target
        var cartItem = buttonLessMore.parentElement
        //var content = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content")[0];
        if (content.className == "open") {
          content.className = ""
          buttonLessMore.innerHTML = "Show More"
        } else {
          content.className = "open"
          buttonLessMore.innerHTML = "Show Less"
        }
      //content.classList.remove("open")
      //content.append(buttonLessMore)
      //content.className += "shop-item"
    })
  } 
</script>

<?php
  $sql = "SELECT `bestellnummer`, `name`, `preis`, `gewuerzart`, `allergieform`, `zutaten`, `kcal`, `menge`, `img` FROM `gerichte` LIMIT 2";
  $db_erg = mysqli_query( $con, $sql );
  if ( ! $db_erg ) { die("Ungültige Abfrage: $sql <hr>" . mysqli_error()); }
  if (mysqli_num_rows($db_erg) > 0) {
  while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg)) {
  echo  '<tr>'; 
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg"><img class="myImg" src ="'. $zeile['img'] .'"></td>';
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg td-content" width="70%">';
  echo          '<div class="show-less-content">';
  echo          '<table>';
  echo              '<tr>'; 
  echo                      '<td>Gericht:</td>';
  echo                      '<td class="shop-item-title">'.$zeile['name'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>';
  echo                      '<td>Bestellnummer:</td>';
  echo                      '<td class="shop-item-title2">'.$zeile['bestellnummer'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>'; 
  echo                      '<td>Allergieinformation:</td>';
  echo                      '<td>'.$zeile['allergieform'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>'; 
  echo                      '<td>Gewürzart:</td>';
  echo                      '<td>'.$zeile['gewuerzart'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>'; 
  echo                      '<td>Zutaten:</td>';
  echo                      '<td>'.$zeile['zutaten'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>'; 
  echo                      '<td>Nährwert:</td>';
  echo                      '<td>'.$zeile['kcal'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr><tr>';
  echo                      '<td>Menge:</td>';
  echo                      '<td>'.$zeile['menge'].'</td>';
  echo                  '</tr>';    
  echo              '</table>';
  echo          '</div>';
  echo          '<button class="show-more">Show More</button>';
  echo      '</td>';
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg-2">';
  echo          '<div>Preis:</div>'; 
  echo          '<div class="shop-item-price ">'.$zeile['preis'].'</div>'; 
  echo      '</td>';    
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg-3">';
  echo          '<button class="btn btn-primary shop-item-button" >In den Warenkorb</button>';
  echo      '</td>';    
  echo  '</tr>'; 
  }
  } else {
  echo 'Es gibt keine Gerichte!';
  }
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok i changed the code a bit to earn the same result.

first: i add an counter, i manipulate the button and the div class

```
echo        '<div class="show-less-content" id="Nr'.$counter.'" >';
```

codeseqment:

```
if (mysqli_num_rows($db_erg) > 0) {
  $counter = 0;
  while ($zeile = mysqli_fetch_assoc($db_erg)) {
  echo  '<tr>'; 
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg"><img class="myImg" src ="'. $zeile['img'] .'"></td>';
  echo      '<td class="tab-cfg td-content" width="70%">';
  echo          '<div class="show-less-content" id="Nr'.$counter.'" >';
  echo          '<table>';
  ..
  .
  echo          '<button class="show-more" onclick="gggggg(Nr'.$counter.')">Show More</button>';
  ..
  .
  echo  '</tr>'; 
  $counter++;
}
} else {
```

then i added an function

```
<script>
  function gggggg(x) {
    if ($(x).hasClass("open") == true ) {
      x.classList.remove("open")
      console.log("closed")
    } 
    else {
      x.classList.add("open")
      console.log("open")
    }
  }
</script>
```

and look at that it works :D

Answer (score -1):

Using an event listener inside a for loop often causes problems because only the last event listener set in the for loop will be alive.
Instead you could add an event listener outside of the for loop on the parent element and get the id of the element that triggered the event.

Comment: thats the problem. i cant figure out how to set the right form. i dont understand that atm the right working form for var x = document.getElementsByClassName("show-less-content"). did you have an example, because if i try to make x[i] it doesnt work?